# Make overflow visible in React Native

Tags: react-native, autocomplete, dropdown

I have been trying to make a component have a dropdown that is visible outside the component container (using zIndex/elevation on the dropdown and overflow: "visible" on the container). But I have not been able to make it working.

```
<SafeAreaView style={[styles.autocompleteContainer]}>
    <View style={[styles.inputContainer]}>
      <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => setQuery(text)} value={query} />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.dropdown}>
      {filteredItems.map((item) => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={item}
            onPress={() => {
              setSelectedItem(item);
              Keyboard.dismiss();
              setFilteredItems([]);
            }}
          >
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
```

And the styles:

```
autocompleteContainer: {
  overflow: 'visible',
  height: 100,
},
inputContainer: {
  ...border,
  marginBottom: 0,
},
dropdown: {
  ...border,
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  elevation: 3,
  overflow: 'visible',
},
```

And I unfortunately cannot use ScrollView for the dropdown since it throws this error:

```
VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show  the whole code please. The error message is not related to the code that you have posted.

Comment: @DavidScholz The bug is for when I use ScrollView instead of filteredItems.map(). I managed to render it without ScrollView and not I deal with the overflow of View that has filteredItems.map() in it.

Comment: I need the whole code. Even if we replace the map() with a ScrollView, this warning will not happen in the current code snippet. You are nesting this component inside another scrollview. This is not currently displayed in your question. I need to see that part.